# How to authenticate with rest webservice using oauth2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

Hello I have a rest web service which implement oauth2.0 .  Now I have my web application with a login which currently using spring security. I want to use the same login to authenticate with  the rest web service using oauth2. My question is: Does this tutorial is suitable for me? https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2014/12/21/implementing-oauth2-with-spring-security/

I just want to authenticate my login with the rest webservice. 
My web application is using hibernate/spring. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web server client part of the tutorial is useful for you. You are not implementing oauth2 provider. The tutorial uses [spring-security-oauth](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) framework.Check [developer guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html).

Comment: Basically from what I have understand,My web application is an oauth consumer ?

Comment: One more thing, How will I know my which grant type my oauth2 provider is using?

Comment: Yes, your application is consumer. Check your provider but it is safe to assume that it will be 'authorization_code'.

Comment: I can see this in the rest web service configuration file:
 authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token"

That means the grant type is password ,same thing as credential password. What about the refresh token?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655911/request-new-access-token-using-refresh-token-in-username-password-grant-in-sprin